# How to navigate between two pages in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-Router-Dom to navigate between two javascript elements in a create-react-app dapp but when I use  it loads the elements on top of the page and just adds the page to the end of the link (localhost/page).

My goal is to have the page reload to the new page on click of the link button with a new background and styling (already done for that page)

App.js Code

```
<Router>
  <s.Screen>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/MyPandas" element={MyPandas} exact></Route>
    </Routes>
          
    /*
      Rest of Code
    */
</Router>
```

My other page is just wrapped in a Fragment Component

```
<Fragment>
  /*
    Code
  */
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

use exact in your Routes e.g : `<Route path='/products' exact>`

Comment: I just added my code with what I have, I added exact the same problem is happening, could you provide further assistance ?

Comment: my bad, exact is no longer supported in react-router-dom v6,

Comment: it's no problem thank you anyways for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your links are working correctly, and it seems they are if the URL in the address bar updates to `"/MyPandas"`.

The issue is that the `element` prop isn't passed a correct value. `react-router-dom@6` `Route` component's `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, not a reference to a React component. Pass `<MyPandas />` instead of `MyPandas`.

```
<Route path="/MyPandas" element={<MyPandas />} />
```

Note: There's no need for the `exact` prop. Not only does it not exist in the RRDv6 `Route` component API, but all routes are now always exactly matched.

Comment: yes this does work but it still loads on top of the main page, I still have App rendered in index.js do you think that may be the error?

Comment: @Doughp What is the "main page"? Do you mean that even when the route matches and `MyPandas` component is rendered that the `App` component is still rendering other content, i.e. the `/* Rest of Code */`? You should place that content into a component rendered by a route as well. Think of the routes as conditionally rendering content.

Comment: yes my "main page" is App.js it was just a one page dapp but I would like to just merge two between navigation and I just copied one into this own page "MyPandas.js" and then I set the code up as shown. Whenever I click My Pandas and the link is "localhost:3000/MyPandas" it renders with the App.js page beneath it.

So will I need to move App.js contents to say MainPage.js and then have App.js just render a navigation hub between the two?

Comment: @Doughp Yes, correct. If you check the console I suspect you'll see a warning about no route for `"/"` path. This is the path you probably want to move this "main page" content into. It doesn't *strictly* need to be this path specifically, but if you're not rendering a route for `path="/"` you'll see the warning. Would you like me to add an example to my answer?

Comment: Yes I believe so unless it would be as simple as adding the element={MainPage} to the one that says path="/"?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for your time brother you have helped me of a major  headache.

Comment: @Doughp Yes, it is about as simple as adding a `<Route path="/" element={/* JSX */} />`. Sounds like you got it.